Unable to remove a record from a Dns Client Cache on Windows 11
I set up a website in IIS on my local machine running Windows 11. It had a domain name secured by SSL. I have since deleted this site from IIS, removed the SSL certificates and moved the site to a remote VPS. I'm not able to navigate to this site from the computer where it was first installed because the dns points me back to my local ip instead of the remote VPS. I am able to navigate to the site from other computers (on and off my network). Running tracert myOldSite.com has one step pointing right back to my laptop's ip address assigned by my router.
tracert results
Command ipconfig /displaydns shows:
myOldSite.com
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : myOldSite.com
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 601675
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
A (Host) Record . . . : 192.168.1.23

and:
23.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : 23.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
Record Type . . . . . : 12
Time To Live  . . . . : 601675
Data Length . . . . . : 8
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
PTR Record  . . . . . : myOldSite.com

These records should not be in the results. I'm not sure where they are coming from and how to stop them from showing up. I've tried running these commands:
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns in that order while restarting the computer as instructed by the output. I installed RSAT: DNS Server Tools and tried Get-DnsServerZone but that fails to enumarate any zones.
nslookup myOldSite.com has the correct remote ip
How can I remove these entries pernamently and stop ii from being cached so I may access the remote site?

Did you happen to add your DNS name to your computer's "Hosts" file? That will override any DNS server/lookup you do.

Perfect! It was in there. I removed it and all works as expected. Thank you

As per Sam's comment, deleting the DNS name from the Hosts file  and flusing DNS resolved the issue. I found the hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
